# Можно ли как-то отслеживать возникающие на устройствах ошибки онлайн?

Tags: java, android, cordova

Я не силен в android разработке, но интересует вопрос, есть ли какие-то сервисы для сбора логов устройств онлайн, error-трекеры для android? Если кто-то использовал посоветуйте какие. Спасибо

Comment: Да можно. https://try.crashlytics.com/ Для отслеживания крешей приложения

Answer (score 0):

в firebase есть Report Crashes on Android
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android